# How does one go about integration testing WPF application

Tags: wpf

Specifically I would like to spin up complete WPF components and automate their testing.

I have read about White and I know there are other commercial frameworks out there based on  System.Windows.Automation.

Answer (score 0):

For simple test automation I would recommend http://testautomationfx.com/